# Issues with MySQL SELECT ordering

Tags: php, mysql, sql

This is not a question of how to optimize the following query for speed, I am aware there are improvements that could be made, but this is to do with the statement's functionality, which does not seem to be selecting data correctly.

**Problem:**

The following query should select users from a list of usernames, ordering them by when they were last messaged (oldest first). Some of the usernames in this list will have never been messaged, and as such `last_message_date` will be `NULL`. However, the current statement returns an order that puts users that have already been messaged (i.e, last_message_date contains a date) before users that have `last_message_date` as NULL.

The weird thing is occasionally it will return it ordered correctly, NULL first, other times it wont. I'm scratching my head here.

**Code:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT username
FROM `account_usernames`
WHERE (`in_progress` = 0)
  AND (account_source IN
         (SELECT DISTINCT `username`
          FROM source_accounts
          WHERE group_users = 'USA Based'
            AND (`type` = 'users'
                 OR `type` = 'both')
            AND `use` = '1'))
  AND (username NOT IN
         (SELECT user_tomsg
          FROM `message_history`
          WHERE owner_account = 'CurrentOwner'))
  AND (username NOT IN
         (SELECT DISTINCT `username`
          FROM `follower_list`))
ORDER BY last_message_date LIMIT ?
FOR
UPDATE;
```

**As said, this occasionally prioritizes users who have been already been messaged, above users who have never been messaged. If anybody can spot an error from this query a response would be warmly appreciated.**

Answer (score 2):

If you want `NULL` values first, then explicitly say so in the `ORDER BY`:

```
ORDER BY (last_message_date is null) desc,
         last_message_date
```

The [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/working-with-null.html) is clear on where `NULL`s are placed when using `ORDER BY`:

> When doing an `ORDER BY`, `NULL` values are presented first if you do
>   `ORDER BY ... ASC` and last if you do `ORDER BY ... DESC`.

The use of `ASC` or `DESC` probably accounts for the differences you see in the placement of these values.